# Get Primary Key out of Zend_Db_Table_Rowset Object

Tags: zend-framework

inside of my Zend_Db_Table_Rowset Object i found this:

```
["_primary:protected"]
```

... does anybody if theres a way to access this? ... maybe something like

```
$rowsetObject->getPrimary()
```

Thanks for your help,
Alex

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Zend_Db_Table_Rowset` has no property `_primary`. What you are refering to is either the `Zend_Db_Table` instance you got the Rowset from or a `Zend_Db_Table_Row` instance inside the Rowset.

For getting the primary key from a `Zend_Db_Table` instance you can do:

```
$tableInstance->info('primary')
```

For getting the primary key from a `Zend_Db_Table_Row` instance you can get the table instance and call `info()` on it:

```
$rowInstance->getTable()->info('primary')
```

Note that this will not work when the row is disconnected, because then `getTable()` will return `null`.

Or, when using a custom `Zend_Db_Table_Row` you can add a method that proxies to `_getPrimaryKey()`:

```
class My_Db_Table_Row extends Zend_Db_Table_Row
{
    public function getPrimaryKey()
    {
        return $this->_getPrimaryKey();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since this variable is protected, you can extend Zend_Db_Table_Rowset and define getPrimary() function yourself, e.g.

```
class My_Zend_Db_Table_Rowset extends Zend_Db_Table_Rowset {
//put your code here

   function getPrimary() {
      return $this->_primary;
   }
}
```