# Zend Framework 1.12: _setupPrimaryKey method of Zend Table

Tags: php, zend-framework

I'm working on fixing bug related to Zend_Db_Table models. The problem that I faced with is that $_primary property of the Zend_Db_Table ancestor mysteriously being changed after you call insert, update etc.

Let's say I have the following value in this field:

```
Class Model_Book extends App_Base_FileForAcs implements App_Interface_OnixDataSource, App_Interface_ApiDataSource, App_Interface_DbGateway
{
protected $_name = 'book';
protected $_primary = 'book_id';
...
}
```

If I check $_primary after insert operation it will contain:

```
array(1) {
[1]=>
string(7) "book_id"
}
```

This transformation happens in _setupPrimaryKey method of Zend_Db_Table_Abstract class. Could you explain why this field should be transformed to array and why array starts with not 0 index?

Answer (score 0):

ZF internally uses an array to define the primary key in order to manage compound keys. It's described here:

http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.db.table.html#zend.db.table.defining.primary-key

The code in _setupPrimaryKey either casts your string to an array with index 1, or if it's already an array, does an `array_unshift($this->_primary, null)` followed by unsetting the _primary[0] to make it 1-based.

To get the primary key (as an array at all times), you'll find more information here: [Get Primary Key out of Zend_Db_Table_Rowset Object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2487523/get-primary-key-out-of-zend-db-table-rowset-object) - that includes how to get it from the table object too.

So, in short - the primary key is always an array, but ZF allows you to define it as a string, for convenience. You never described your bug, but if you rely on the primary key being a string, reading the $_primary directly, you should probably refactor to get the key using `$objZenDbTable->info('primary')` instead, fully expecting an array.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. My issue was that I expected that array starts with index 0 like in any other places. Why ZF decided to start this array with 1 - are there any special reasons for that?

Comment: No, I'm not sure why they've implemented it that way. There is a function that tries to figure out the primary key from the table metadata, then setting the index to the column(s) relative position(s) in the the table definition. There's also some mention of some special case for PostgreSQL that might use that index somehow. Since any "hard coded" index keys are indexed at 1 like you say, I don't see how it would make any difference. Perhaps it's some work-in-progress that never got completed? You'll find the code around line 872 in `Zend\Db\Table\Abstract.php` if you want to dig deeper.